# Merge tags [rasa-nlu] and [rasa-core] to [rasa] as they are deprecated

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I'm a Machine Learning Solutions Architect at [Rasa](https://rasa.com).

Nurturing our open source community is part of our [mission statement](https://rasa.com/mission/), and as part of this we are working hard to provide answers to our users on Stack Overflow.

In April of this year we [announced](https://forum.rasa.com/t/merging-rasa-core-and-nlu-repositories/7099) we would be combining our two repositories Rasa NLU & Rasa Core into one piece of open source software: [Rasa](https://github.com/rasahq/rasa).  To avoid confusion on Stack Overflow and to simplify the tags, could I ask that the tags [rasa-nlu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rasa-nlu) (318 questions) and [rasa-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rasa-core) (199 questions) now **both** be merged under the new [rasa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rasa) tag?

Comment: Is it possible for users to use an older version of the software, which would mean these "older" tags would still be accurate?

Comment: Though they could still install the final releases from pip, the source code for both rasa-nlu and rasa-core is still contained under the new repository, so any questions using those tags would be covered by the new one.